# wmode="opaque" causes selection on textarea to behave wierdly after mouse is pressed and left stage

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5, flash-10

I m using textarea in flash 10 cs5 as3. The problem is when i try to select a text and go out of stage and leave the mouse then again move mouse on text then selection of text will move with the mouse.

Here is what causes that:

```
* click somewhere on the text and drag the mouse in order to select the text
* then go out of the swf
* leave the mouse
* now move mouse on textarea
```

-> the selection of text will move with the mouse...

How to stop this behavior????

I tried to implement mouseleave on stage but the problem is i m not able to detect mouseleave event when mouse is pressed and it leaves the stage.

This is because of wmode="opaque" parameter. I found out that it doesn't do this when wmode="window". Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

IF you are using TLF TextField and events are attached to TextField and a is the name of the TextField then try this code

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

a.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN , startdrag);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopdrag);

function startdrag(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    a.startDrag(true);
}

function stopdrag(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    a.stopDrag();
}
```

Comment: hi thanks for replying. But i m using fl.controls.TextArea so can't use start and stop drag. thanks for help. Regards